# checkbox data-bind using knockout.js and jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, knockout.js

I am facing problem to data-bind checkbox using knockout.js.
The jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sajesh1985/ypbLN/

(HTML)Code:

```html
<h2>View1</h2>
<h4>Select Columns:</h4>
<ul data-bind="foreach: gridOptions.columns" data-role="listview">
<div data-role="fieldcontain" >
<li id="li">     
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="chk" data-bind="event: {change: function(){ checked(!checked()); } }, checkbox: checked" /> <span data-bind="text: header"></span>
    </label>
</li>
</div>
</ul>
<hr>
<table>
<thead>
    <tr data-bind="foreach: gridOptions.columns">
        <th data-bind="visible:checked, text: header"></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: people">
    <tr data-bind="foreach: $parent.gridOptions.columns">
        <td data-bind="text: $parent[dataMember], visible:checked"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

JS Code:

```js
var ProductSearchViewModel = {

gridOptions: {
    columns: [{
        header: 'First Name',
        dataMember: 'firstName',
        checked: ko.observable(true)
    }, {
        header: 'Last Name',
        dataMember: 'lastName',
        checked: ko.observable(true)
    }]
},

people: [{
    firstName: 'Bert',
    lastName: 'Bertington'
}, {
    firstName: 'Charles',
    lastName: 'Charlesforth'
}, {
    firstName: 'Denise',
    lastName: 'Dentiste'
}]


};

ko.bindingHandlers.checkbox = {
update: function (element, valueAccessor) {

    var value = valueAccessor();

    var valueUnwrapped = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value);

    //$(element).checkboxradio().trigger('create');               
    $(element).attr("checked", valueUnwrapped).checkboxradio("refresh");

}
};

$(document).ready(function () {
ko.applyBindings(ProductSearchViewModel);    
});
```

Can you please help me in rectifying the issue?
I am getting Uncaught cannot call methods on checkboxradio prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh' in the browser.

Comment: It's difficult to give you a solution without your code posted here. From the error, you trigger(refresh) before creating checkbox or change their properties.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to bind checkboxes is to use the *checked* binding like here:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chk" data-bind="checked: checked" />
```

See also documentation: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html

Comment: agree but this has an issue with jquery mobile custom checkbox